# IIS 7. Not authorized to perform the current operation

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm running IIS7 on Windows 2008. Recently, one of the web sites just stopped allowing me to connect via Frontpage Server Extensions 2002. Visual Studio keeps coming up with the error, "Unable to open the Web site '...'. You are not authorized to perform the current operation." No pop-up authentication appears, just an error in the output window.

Other sites on the same server still work properly (authentication box pops up to prompt for credentials.)

Anonymous and Basic Authentication are enabled on all sites.

Here are some of the things I tried, to no avail:

1. Completely removed and reinstalled Server Extension 2002 on the site.
2. Completely removed folder and website, and recreated the site.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  Turned out it was a Visual Studio issue.  Right-clicking on the project in the Project Explorer window and selecting refresh folder forced the authentication prompt to come up, and the error never returned.

I am guessing Visual Studio may have had some type of cached credential feature that may have caused this.